# JOLT: array item string to integer conversion

Tags: json, jolt

How can I transform a specific item in an array to integer? In the following example, I want only the 3rd element `456` to be converted to integer, and `123` to be left intact:

input:

```json
{
  "arr": [
    "hello",
    "123",
    "456"
  ]
}
```

Trying this spec:

```json
[
    {
        "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
        "spec": {
            "arr": "=toInteger"
        }
    }
]
```

I get actual output:

```json
{
  "arr": [
    "hello",
    123,
    456
  ]
}
```

However, the desired output should look like this:
expected output:

```json
{
  "arr": [
    "hello",
    "123",
    456
  ]
}
```

Thank you,
Gerasimos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get

```json
{
  "arr": [
    "hello",
    123,
    456
  ]
}
```

for the current case. Just need to restrict to the index(`2`) of the desired element within the spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "arr": {
        "[2]": "=toInteger"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

in order to get the desired result, that's :

```json
{
  "arr": [
    "hello",
    "123",
    456
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the actual output in the OP.